# Image Analysis Program Crashing - not sure why

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am attempting to make an app using the android studio that allows the user to choose a photo from their gallery, and then determines the brightest area in the picture. It does this by analyzing a smaller portion of the image and summing up all the pixels in that region. Attaching my code and the error I am getting below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
      public void onImageGalleryClicked(View v) {

        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();
        Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);
        photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //if we are here, everything has been processed successfully
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream inputStream;

                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                     Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                     int w = image.getWidth();
                    int h = image.getHeight();
                    pixels = new int[4*w*h];
                    int a = 20; //this is the width of the smaller image that we are cropping to sum up
                    int b = 20; ////this is the length(height) of the smaller image that we are cropping to sum up
                    int tempmax = 0;
                    int sum = 0;
                    int k = 0;
                  for (int i =0; i< h - b; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < w-a; j++) {
                            image.getPixels(pixels, k*i+j,0, j, i, a, b);
                            for (int e = 0; e < a*b; e++) {
                                sum = sum + pixels[e+k*i+j];
                            }

                            if (sum > tempmax) {
                                tempmax = sum;

                            }
                            sum = 0;
                        }
                        k = k + 1;
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
02 - 18 21: 57: 08.794 7681 - 7681 / com.example.garrett.debuggingcode E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.garrett.debuggingcode, PID: 7681
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo {
        who = null, request = 20, result = -1, data = Intent {
                dat = content: //media/external/images/media/217 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.garrett.debuggingcode/com.example.garrett.debuggingcode.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: abs(stride) must be >= width
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java: 4556)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java: 4599)
                at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1715)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6823)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1557)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1445)
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: abs(stride) must be >= width
                at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess(Bitmap.java: 1896)
                at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java: 1844)
                at com.example.garrett.debuggingcode.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java: 73)
                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java: 7322)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java: 4552)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java: 4599) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1715) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6823) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1557) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1445)
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: Returns in pixels[] a copy of the data in the bitmap. Each value is a packed int representing a Color. The stride parameter allows the caller to allow for gaps in the returned pixels array between rows. For normal packed results, just pass width for the stride value. The returned colors are non-premultiplied ARGB values in the sRGB color space.
Your stride zero now.